# Matched lines (with regex) being written to both output files, but it's supposed only to be written to one output file..

Tags: perl

I have a tab-delimited text file with several rows. I wrote a script in which I assign the rows to an array, and then I search through the array by means of regular expressions, to find the rows that match certain criteria. When a match is found, I write it to Output1. After going through all the if-statements listed (the regular expressions) and the criteria still isn't met, then the line is written to Output 2.

I works 100% when it comes to matching criteria and writing to Output 1, but here is where my problem comes in:
The matched lines are also being written to Output2, along with the unmatched lines. I am probably making a silly mistake, but I really just can't see it. If someone could have a look and help me out, I'd really appreciate it..

Thanks so much! :)

```
Inputfile sample:
skool   school
losieshuis  pension
prys    prijs
eeu    eeuw
lys lijs
water   water
outoritêr   outoritaire


#!/usr/bin/perl-w
use strict;
use warnings;
use open ':utf8';
use autodie;

open OSWNM, "<SecondWordsNotMatched.txt";
open ONIC, ">Output1NonIdenticalCognates.txt";
open ONC, ">Output2NonCognates.txt";

while (my $line = <OSWNM>)
{
    chomp $line;        
    my @Row = $line;

    for (my $x = 0; $x <= $#Row; $x++)
    {
        my $RowWord = $Row[$x];

#Match: anything, followed by 'y' or 'lê' or 'ê', followed by anything, followed by 
a tab, followed by anything, followed by 'ij' or 'leggen' or 'e', followed by anything

      if ($RowWord =~ /(.*)(y|lê|ê)(.*)(\t)(.*)(ij|leggen|e)(.*)/)
      {
        print ONIC "$RowWord\n";
      }


#Match: anything, followed by 'eeu', followed by 'e' or 's', optional, followed by 
anyhitng, followed by a tab, followed by anything, followed by 'eeuw', followed by 'en', optional

      if ($RowWord =~ /(.*)(eeu)(e|s)?(\t)(.*)(eeuw)(en)?/)
    {
        print ONIC "$RowWord\n";
      }

      else
    {
        print ONC "$RowWord\n";
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Well if your string matches both patterns, it will get printed twice to ONIC. It doesnt seem that the two matches are mutually exclusive in which case it will get printed twice.

Answer (score 2):

Inside your loop you essentially have:

```
if (A) {
  output to file1
}

if (B) {
  output to file1
} else {
  output to file2
}
```

So you'll `output to file2` anything that doesn't satisfy `B` (regardless of whether `A` was satisfied or not), and output stuff that satisfies both `A` and `B` twice to `file1`.

If outputting twice was not intended, you should modify your logic to something like:

```
if (A or B) {
  output to file1
} else {
  output to file2
}
```

Or:

```
if (A) {
  output to file1
} elsif (B) {
  output to file1
} else {
  output to file2
}
```

(This second version allows you to do different processing for the `A` and `B` cases.)

If the double output was intended, you could do something like:

```
my $output_to_file2 = 1;

if (A) {
  output to file1
  $output_to_file2 = 0;
}

if (B) {
  output to file1
  $output_to_file2 = 0;
}

if ($output_to_file2) {
  output to file2
}
```

Comment: maybe if (A) {..} elsif (B) {..} else {..}  could be used

Comment: Sure. Added an example with that.

Comment: Thank you so much, the 'elsif' instead of just the 'if' has done the trick! :)